# How to Prove that hyperplane is facet defining?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, affine-geometry, polyhedra

I met the following statement without proof:

> If the dimension of a polyhedron $P\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is $d,$ then a valid for $P$ inequality $\alpha^T x ≤ b$ is facet defining for $P$ if and only if $P$ contains $d$ affinely independent points lying on the hyperplane $H(a;b)=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:\alpha^T x = b\} $.$

The proof of necessity is almost obvious:

If inequality $\alpha^T x ≤ b$ is facet defining for $P,$ therefore $\{x\in P:\alpha^T x = b\} $ is facet for $P.$ The dimension of every facet of P is $d − 1.$ This means that $P$ contains $d$ affinely independent points lying on the hyperplane $H(a;b).$

But how to prove sufficiency?

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of a "facet-defining" hyperplane of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for a polyhedron of dimension $d$ is not so obvious when $d<n$. Here I assume it is facet-defining iff the intersection of the hyperplane and the polyhedron has at least dimension $d-1$, and the polyhedron is entirely on one side of the hyperplane.

Suppose $P$ contains $d$ affinely independent points lying on the hyperplane $H(\alpha;b)$.
The convex hull $C$ of these $d$ points has dimension $d-1$.
A polyhedron being convex, $C \subset P$.
As all $d$ points verify $\alpha^Tx=b$, by linearity each point in $C$ verifies $\alpha^Tx=b$, so $C \subset H(\alpha;b)$.

So the intersection of $H(\alpha;b)$ and $P$ includes $C$, which is of dimension $d-1$: the intersection is at least of dimension $d-1$. And $P$ is entirely on one side of the hyperplane as we have the hypothesis that the inequality $\alpha^Tx \le b$ is valid for $P$.

Comment: thanks for your help.

By the way, I have a slightly different definition, in comparison with the one you proposed:

Let $P$ be a polyhedron. A facet of $P$ is an (inclusion-wise) maximal face
$F$ of $P$ with $F\neq P$. An inequality $c^Tx ≤ \delta$ is facet-defining for $P$ if $c^Tx ≤ \delta$ for all
$x \in P$ and $\{x \in P: c^Tx = \delta\}$ is a facet.

How to connect these two definitions?

Comment: @ИванПетров That's true. Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facet_(geometry)) gives both definitions and says they coincide when considering pure simplicial complexes. And polytopes are pure simplicial complexes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_complex (well, at least one definition of polytopes...). Otherwise your definition is larger than mine, i.e. it includes elements that have a smaller dimension, if considering a non-pure simplicial complex.

Comment: @ИванПетров Two remarks: 1) The statement you quoted says "polyhedron" but "polytope" is better, as polyhedron is usually dimension 3. 2) In my demonstration I say "a polyhedron being convex". But there are non-convex polyhedra. :-) But for them, the quoted statement is wrong (at least for a reasonable interpretation of "facet-defining"). I believe convexity is implicit here, because dealing with inequalities and facet-defining hyperplanes is usually in a convex optimization context, where the feasible domaine is defined by linear inequalities, hence convex.

Comment: Thanks again for your help

I have already found in one source (Theorem 3.44 (Characterization of facets), https://userpages.uni-koblenz.de/~davidwillems/ip-chapter1.pdf) what helped me: in order for a face to be a facet, it is necessary and sufficient to have a dimension less than one than the polyhedron ( dim(Facet) = dim(Polyhedron) - 1 ). Then I can "turn back" the proof of necessity and get sufficiency.

Comment: Yes, I am interested in convex (or rather MIP) optimization. Therefore, I am expanding the knowledge base, perhaps too carefully than I should be doing it. Most of the sources I read: a Polyhedron means a system of inequalities $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n : Ax\leq b\},$ While a polytope is the convex hull of a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n.$